# Adding Silverlight webpart does nothing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am adding silverlight webpart in my sharepoint foundation site but nothing happens and no webparts appears? why is it so?

Comment: Check to see if you have silverlight installed.

Comment: Silverlight webpart is now adding but when I am loading the xap from ClientBin it says "Could not download the Silverlight application.
"

Comment: It sounds like the page can't see the xap file. View source on the page and browse the location where the xap should be. Also do a full clear of your browsers cache.

Comment: did but still not working

Comment: So you can browse to the xap file location manually?

Comment: Yes, I have place Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.xap in my sitesasset lib

Comment: Check to see if xap is registered as a mime type on your iis server.

Comment: yes it is registered.

Comment: Not enough room to show all mime types here to check so I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got a copy of all the mime types you need in iis off my sysmanager:

The error will probably be related to one of these:

**.xaml**                              application/xaml+xml

**.xap**                                application/x-silverlight-app

**.manifest**                         application/manifest

**.application**                      application/x-ms-application

**.xbap**                              application/x-ms-xbap

**.deploy**                           application/octet-stream

**.xps**                               application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument